# Уникальный ключ андроид приложения

Tags: android, root

При разработке андроид-приложения столкнулся с проблемой - необходимо отследить уникальность устройства ( 1 аккаунт == 1 устройство). Все найденные способы, обходятся через ROOT. Есть способ создания такого ключа, который точно идентифицирует устройство ?

Comment: Guid нельзя сгенерировать при установке приложения?

Comment: При переустановке приложения будет новый ключ? В таком случае этот метод не подойдет.

Comment: Тогда встречный вопрос вам- как отличить устройство которое впервые установит вашу программу, от устройства которое переустановило программу?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

Comment: Главное  - определить устройство. А переустановка приложения не важна. Задача состоит в реализации защитной системы от мультиаккаунтов.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы отследить уникальность устройства, вы можете получить специальный id устройства, именно он является уникальным.

Для этого вам в манифесте нужно прописать:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

и в определенном месте получить id:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```